# Why a[0] is returning 1 and a[1] returning 0 and so on?

Tags: ruby

I just found a question in a quiz where I noticed this weird behavior of a variable:

```
a = 5
puts a[0]  # Output 1
puts a[1]  # Output 0
```

Can anyone please explain me why I am getting the output 1 and 0?

Comment: _"weird behavior of a variable"_ – `a[0]` is simply `5[0]` – it has nothing to do with variables.

Comment: `5[0]` is called *syntactic sugar* for `5.[](0)`. That is, Ruby allows to write the latter as the former. `[]` may look like an odd name for a method but that’s what it is. Where is the method defined? You can do the following for any method and receiver: `5.method(:[]).owner #=> Integer`. This tells you that the method’s doc is found at [Integer#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D). Follow this approach to get the doc for any method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) for an integer returns a nth bit in the binary representation:

```
7.downto(0) {|n| print 5[n] }
00000101=> 8
```

`5` is `0101` in binary, so `5[0]` returns `1` (first from right-hand side, the least significant bit), then `5[1]` is `0` a `5[2]` is `1`.